# If $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ has $|a_n| \to r$, where do possible subsequences of $a_n$ converge to?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Assume that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of complex numbers for which $(|a_n|)$ is convergent to a real number $r > 0$. Prove that $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence. What are the possible limits of convergent subsequences of $(a_n)$ in terms of $r$?

I can proof that there is a convergent subsequence. Let $\epsilon > 0$. There is $N$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N$, we have $||a_n| - r| < 1$. Thus, for $n \geq N$: $|a_n| < 1+r$, whence for all $n$, $|a_n| \leq M$ where $M= \sup\{|a_1|, |a_2|, \dots, |a_{N-1}|, 1+r\}.$
 Thus, $a_n$ is bounded, whence it has a convergent subsequence by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

This suggests that possible convergent subsequences converge to $a$ s.t. $|a| \leq M$. Is that all we can conclude? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $a_n$ has a subsequence which convereges to $a$, what is $|a|$?

Comment: Is it given by |a| = r?

Comment: It is not given, but maybe you can prove it?  @LeonM

Comment: Let $b_n$ be a subsequence of $a_n$. Then $|b_n|$ is a subsequence of $|a_n|$. But $|a_n| \to r$, whence $|b_n| \to r$. And the modulus is a continuous function, and thus $|a| = r$?

Comment: Yes, @LeonM. Exactly.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!